# Deja-Dup does not remember network share password even though "remember password" box was ticked

Tags: lubuntu, password, deja-dup

Using Deja-Dup to back up to a network share from a Lubuntu 18.04.1 laptop.

Deja-Dup properly asks for credentials for the share, and offers the option to save the password by ticking a box. Which I do. The backup goes as desired, no problem.

The next time I do a backup, I have to input the credentials again.  Ticking the "save password" box does not, in fact, save the password.

Could this be a keyring problem? I've had keyring issues with Lubuntu before.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It will remember the password if you place your userid in the Network Location box, like this example:

```
smb://WORKGROUP;[username]@[ip-address]/[share]/[folder]
```